# WKWebView scrollview delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have several page views and each one has a webview. All references are strong. Everything works fine except the usage of the webview scrollview and setting its delegate. I use it to listen to scroll events.

When setting the delegate of the webview.scrollview and popping the current view this happens:

```
    objc[37721]: Cannot form weak reference to
instance (0x7fb988fe2800) of class WebViewPageController.
    It is possible that this object was over-released,
or is in the process of deallocation.
```

I notice in the stack trace in XCode that this happens in:

```
WKWebView dealloc
WKWebView _updateDelegate
UIScrollView setDelegate
```

What can I do to fix this? This worked well when using UIWebView but now upgrading to WKWebView this happens. Is there a new way to listen to scroll events?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Implement the deinit method in your view controller and set the scroll views delegate to nil:

```
deinit {
    webView.scrollView.delegate = nil
}
```

Comment: I was using Objective-C and eventually used the dealloc method to set the delegate to nil. So this is exactly the correct answer, nice one. This is an issue with WKWebView since the same implementation of UIWebView does not require it.

Comment: Solved my problem